# How to Use Github project as jar file in current sbt library

Tags: scala, github, sbt

I am new to sbt.

I have one project say `XYZ` which is using a JAR file called `ABC.jar`.

Currently I am making the ABC.jar from the github project which is also my repo. `ABC.jar` contains some model classes.

Now my problem is every time I change in `ABC` I have to manually build a JAR file and put it in the `lib` folder of `XYZ` project.

I would like to directly include `ABC.jar` in `XYZ`.

Can you please suggest how I include the JAR from the `ABC` github project in my `XYZ` projects's sbt file?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to publish your `ABC` repo as a library on something like maven central.

You can check out a guide on how to do this here: http://www.loftinspace.com.au/blog/publishing-scala-libraries-to-sonatype.html

Then you could specify `ABC` as a dependency for `XYZ` and have sbt do the rest.

Comment: No I dont want to use ABC as repo

Answer (score 2):

You can add a lib folder to your classpath's folder and then sbt will find it.

The first part "Unmanaged Dependencies" might help you.
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html

The base folder might be the folder your "build.sbt" is placed in. Therefore you'll need to create a folder "lib" in the same folder where your "build.sbt" is placed.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `sbt` to depend on github project directly, without jar step. See http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse.

(this is not an answer to stated issue, but to the root cause; hope this might be useful)